# Is it possible for a webapp to access a native Android app's sqlite db?

Tags: javascript, android, html, sqlite, android-studio

I really need to get an imei number to my webapp to register the device. I have made a simple native Android app that gets the imei and was hoping to put the number somewhere locally on the device that the web app could then come and check for.

I can put the imei in an sqlite db ok from the Android side of things, but not sure if I can access that specific info from the webapp.

Would there be a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqlite db created by a native app is sandboxed for access by other applications. So you cannot do what you are trying to do.

Add your web application as a webview along with your app that provides you the imei number. Then your webview will have access to the sqlite db or the IMEI number directly.

If you are trying to authenticate the device using IMEI info then it will be a wrong approach as this information can be easily faked. At the most IMEI should be used as a username and not as a password.

## a quick hack

Use the native app to get the imei.
From the app Generate a URL like this www.yourdomain.com/'Replace_with_IMEI_NUMBER'
Once the user clicks with some client side server side coding you 
can store the received IMEI number in the browsers Local storage.

The next time your web app is opened you will get access to the local storage which contains the imei number.

But once the local storage is cleared this step has to be repeated.

Comment: Brilliant. Just made a demo using your 'quick hack' strategy. Works like a charm. I can check in my web app that the localstorage value exists, if not, I just block access until they re-register. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can access the db application Android. But you might save the imei in a DB to be questioned later.